# Проблемы с созданием метода для класса

Tags: классы, java, методы

Здравствуйте! Начал осваивать ООП и столкнулся с проблемой, решил написать класс matematik и несколько методов в нем. Первым стал возведение в степень. Вот код:

```
public class matematik {
  public int result;
  public int erection (int a, int n) {
      if (n>0) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result = 1;
            result = result * a;
        }
      return result;
    }
      if (n<0){
          for(int i = n; i <= 1; i++){
              result = 1;
              result = result/a;
          }
        return result;
      }
  }
}
```

Эклипс ругается на вот эту строчку "public int erection (int a, int n)"

> This method must return a result of type int.

Подскажите новичку, что я делаю не так?

Comment: >This method must return a result

действительно, у эреккции должен быть какой-то результат

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// matematik - неправильно, правильно mathematic. 
// а кроме того в java принято называть классы с заглавной
class Mathematic {
    // есть смысл сделать метод статичным, 
    // - т.к. его выполнение не повлияет на состояние класса
    public static int power(int base, int power) {

        // эта переменная не может быть полем
        // потому что нет смысла хранить временные данные за пределами данного
        // метода
        int result = 0;
        if (power > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
                result = 1;
                result = result * base;
            }
            // мы в любом случае будем возвращать результат
            // посему именно здесь можно не возвращать результат
            // return result;
        } else if (power < 0) {
                    // чутье подсказывает что этот код работает неправильно    
            for (int i = power; i <= 1; i++) {
                result = 1;
                result = result / base;
            }
            // мы в любом случае будем возвращать результат
            // посему именно здесь можно не возвращать результат
            // return result;
        }

        // результат возвращаем в любом случае
        return result;
    }
}
```

имеет смысл рассмотреть частные случаи:
1) степень равна 0
2) степень равна 1
3) степень меньше 0
4) степень - дробное число

последний частный случай подразумевает что у вас степень может быть не только целочисленным значением, но еще и дробным. а посему лучше поменять тип данных int на double, но не думаю что есть смысл рассматривать этот вариант, т.к. его реализация не так уж проста. с другой стороны возможность задания негативной степени показывает что на входе функции может быть дробное число (5^-2 = 1/5^2 = 1/25).

код учитывая все вышесказанное:

```
public static double power(double base, int power) {
        // сначала обрабатываем частные случаи
        // это нужно чтоб наш код не делал лишних действий

        // возведение 0 в любую степень даст 0
        // в случае когда степень будет отрицательной
        // придется делить на 0
        if (0 == base) {
            return 0;
        }

        // если степень равна единице, то выполнять возведение бесполезно
        // if (1.0 == power) { - неправильно (1.0 имеет тип double)
            // спасибо @avp что заметил, так будет правильно     
        if (1 == power) {
            return base;
        }

        // если степень отрицательная: то 2^(-3) = 1/(2^3)
        if (0 > power) {
            return power(1 / base, -power);
        }

        // будет хранить результат в этой переменой
        double result = base;

        // само вычисление
        for (int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
            result = result * base;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо огромное и отдельный плюс за комментарии ) как они порой важны для начинающего )

Comment: великолепный ответ

Comment: @jmu, отличное объяснениние. Мне только не ясен смысл (1.0 == power) для int power.

Comment: еще непонятно в первой части зачем result=1 внутри цикла, хотя это вопрос  больше к ТС, видимо.
во второй части power(100,0) вернет 100. и без дробной степени скучно...
**upd** power(0,-1) вернет 0.

Comment: 2 @avp: если степень равна единице, то результатом будет само число. нет смысла идти дальше и делать другие проверки. а на счет ".0" вы правы его там быть не должно. просто сначала я писал метод для аргументов double, но передумал, по понятным причинам

Comment: всё же не совсем понятно для чего static, ведь чем их меньше - тем лучше?

Answer (score 2):

Надо перед 2 с конца скобки добавить return null;

Comment: спасибо вам)

Comment: Только не null, а 0 (метод все таки, как int объявлен).

@Константин25, Вы рассмотрели (и завершили return-ом) два случая, а про третий (n == 0) забыли. Eclipse в своей манере сообщил Вам это.